# Gate set auth model as 2nd arg for auth callback when using custom guard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

- Horizon Version: ^5.7
- Laravel Version: ^8.18
- PHP Version: ^8.0
- Redis Driver & Version: predis/phpredis ^1.1

#### Description:

**When i tried to use a custom guard for my authorisation logic then i was able to access the authenticated object from the 2nd callback argument instead of the first argument.**

#### Steps To Reproduce:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

class HorizonServiceProvider extends HorizonApplicationServiceProvider
{
...
  protected function authorization()
    {
        $this->gate();

        Horizon::auth(function ($request) {
            return app()->environment('local') ||
                   Gate::check('viewHorizon', [$request->user('web:admin')]);
                  // used custom guard
        });
    }
  
  protected function gate()
    {
        Gate::define(
          'viewHorizon',
          fn ($user = null, $admin = null) =>
          // 2nd arg = $admin has the authenticated object
          // # unexpected behaviour
            ($admin ? $admin::class : null) == Admin::class
        );
    }
}
```

Is this the normal behaviour? or could there be something i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the custom guard in the Horizon configuration file: `config/horizon.php`. In my case:

```php
<?php

return [
    ...
    'middleware' => ['web','auth:admin'],
    ...
];
```

Then in `HorizonServiceProvider` you should check the user role:

```php
Gate::define('viewHorizon', function ($user) {
    return $user instanceof AdminUser && $user->isAdmin();
});
```

Note that to apply the above Gate you should change the environment to `production` at `.env` file. To know why, please take a look at `vendor/laravel/horizon/src/HorizonApplicationServiceProvider.php`:

```php
Horizon::auth(function ($request) {
    return app()->environment('local') ||
           Gate::check('viewHorizon', [$request->user()]);
});
```

Comment: did you know that `middleware`:`auth:admin` will force your route to be authenticated even if you are on local env?
so i don't want horizon routes to be authenticated on `local` env.